# Removing all empty .bz2 files from a folder

Tags: compression, bz2

I have a folder (actually on HDFS but I don't think that affects the question) of .bz2 files. Some of these when decompressed give single empty files. I would like to remove all the .bz2 files which decompress to empty and I notice that they all have size 14 bytes. Is it safe to simply remove all 14 byte files? Or is it possible for a non-empty file to compress to/decompress from a 14 byte bz2?

Answer (score 0):

BZ2 is a compressed file format used by Bzip 2. Bzip 2 is an open and free compression program created by Julian Seward. BZ2 files use Burrows-Wheeler compression algorithm combined with Run-Length Encoding (RLE) for maximum compression.[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2)

If you like to delete those files, first use the below code snippet to get the details of .gz file.

unzipping the gz2 file

```
gunzip -c test.bz2 | hadoop fs -put - /path/filepath
```

to read the contents

```
hadoop fs -text /path_for_hdfs/test.bz2 | hadoop fs -put /hdfs_path/abc.txt
```

Comment: I don't really want to have to unzip all the files though...the question is can I guarantee a 14 byte bz2 is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I created an empty text file and compressed with bzip2 and inserted into hdfs.
The size for the empty bzip2 file was 14B.
When I did same with the non-empty file (only one character) it was 39bytes.

my conclusion is that all 14B bzip2 file will be empty.

make your own desition based on test cases...

[image]

Comment: But can anybody explain WHY a 14 byte bz2 file will always decompress to an empty file? I.e. Your answer seems to be based on inductive reasoning but where potential data loss is concerned I would feel more secure with an answer based on deductive reasoning.

Comment: "WHY a 14 byte bz2 file will always decompress to an empty file."

An empty file which is compressed using bzip2 will be 14B. 
but I don't know the exact reason for that  14B size

Comment: I accept that, but might a nonempty file also compress to 14 bytes for some reason? It is not enough to show that a single character compresses to more than 14 bytes as a compression algorithm could easily be postulated that compresses say 8, 16 or 32 copies of a character to less space than a single character. I am hoping that someone with domain specific knowledge of bz2 can supply an answer...